# Using the word poetry with "the"

Tags: definite-articles

I'm trying to say that someone wrote a certain type of poetry that he particularly liked. Is it correct to express it like the following?

**In those days he was mainly writing the lyric poetry that was so dear to him.**

I did find usage examples that matched this structure, but they were very few so I wanted to make sure.

Comment: It's correct -- another way of saying "poetry in the lyric mode which was so dear to him."

Comment: Yeah, it's fine.

Comment: Yup.  Perfectly okay.

Answer (score 1):

> In those days he was mainly writing the lyric poetry that was so dear to him.

Yes, it is correct. It's identical in structure to,

*In those days he was mainly driving the ford car that was so dear to him.*

*In those days he was mainly fighting the old battle that was so important to him.*

*In those days he was mainly eating the spicy food that was so appealing to him.*